# fork() returns positive number instead of zero

Tags: c, process, fork

I'm having an issue of understanding why fork() returns positive number instead of zero when i use it only once in the code.i have been searching for a solution for few hours but nothing helped me.
this is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //for exit
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h> //for sleep(),execvp()
#include <ctype.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define IN 0
#define OUT 1
#define SIZE 9
    int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
        int pipe_descs[2];
        int matrix[SIZE][SIZE];
        int fdr, fdw;   // file descriptors
        int i;
           int status=0;
        /*if (pipe(pipe_descs) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot open");
            exit(1);
        }*/
                fdr = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);   // open files
                fdw = open("gg.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
             if (fdr < 0 || fdw < 0) { //validation for error
                 perror("failed to open input or output files");
                 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
             }
            removeSpaces(matrix, fdr, fdw);
             status=fork();
            if (status < 0) {
                fputs("error in fork", stderr);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
             if(status == 0) {
                    printf("got to child"); 
                    dup2(pipe_descs[IN],0);
                    close(pipe_descs[IN]);
                    dup2(pipe_descs[OUT],4);
                    close(STDOUT_FILENO);


            }

        close(fdr);   // close the files
        close(fdw);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
```

Comment: Are you judging whether the if-statement works based on whether you see the "got to child" message? Can you try fflush(stdout) after the printf in the child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time `fork()` returns, you have two (almost) identical processes running - the parent and the child. As if you ran your program twice.

The parent process gets a positive return from the fork() - the PID of the child process. The child gets a zero.

The line "got to child" is not printed because `printf` buffers the output until the newline character is printed, and you close the stdout handle before it gets a chance to flush the buffer. Either insert a `\n` at the end of it, or remove the `close(STDOUT_FILENO)` line.

Comment: i get you but i still don't understand why the if condition doesn't work

Comment: The `status==0` condition works in one process (the child) and doesn't work in the other (the parent), 'cause for the parent process, the status is legitimately zero. The code after fork() is executed in two processes, twice.

Comment: In theory your right the face that it doesn't print the printf line with i run it.

Comment: `printf` buffers the output until the newline. You kill the `stdout` console handle before the text gets a chance to print. Remove the `close` line and see. Alternatively, add \n to the "Got to child" string.

Comment: ... or use `fclose(stdout)` instead of `close(STDOUT_FILENO)`.  `fclose()` will flush the stream's buffer before closing the underlying file.  But the suggestion to just let the system close the standard streams automatically when the program terminates (which will include flushing their buffers) is the most conventional.

Answer (score 0):

`fork()` returns PID (process id) of the child on success in the parent process.  -1 on failure.  See this excerpt from `man fork` (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html):

> On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent,
>   and 0 is returned in the child.  On failure, -1 is returned in the
>   parent, no child process is created, and errno is set appropriately.

Comment: i have used pid_t and i played with it a little bit.every place that i have searched either online or not said that when i create it the child suppose to be zero

Comment: It's 0 in the forked child process.  But in the parent process fork() returns pid of the child.